# How can collections of rational zeta series that are equal to $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\zeta(n) - 1)^{p} $ be obtained?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function

It has been discovered long ago that

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \big(\zeta(n) - 1\big) = 1. \label{1} \tag{1} $$ More recently, a generalization of this result with binomial coefficients has been obtained: $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {k+v+1 \choose k+1}\big(\zeta(k+v+2)-1\big)=1, \label{2}\tag{2}$$
where $v$ is a complex number. Identity \eqref{2} amounts to identity \eqref{1} when $v=0$. One could also look at another type of generalization of \eqref{1} by considering series of the form $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\big(\zeta(n)-1\big)^{p} \label{3}\tag{3}$$ for positive integer values of $p$. As far as I [know](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373231/what-is-known-about-sums-of-the-form-sum-n-2-infty-zetan-1p), series of this type have not been evaluated yet for $p \geq 2$.

Even though series of the form \eqref{3} have not been evaluated so far, I wonder whether we can find families of series that amount to the same values, in the same way that the family of series in \eqref{2} is equal to the series in \eqref{1}.

My question, in other words, is whether we can find sequences of positive integer coefficients $c(n,v,p)$ such that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\big(\zeta(n)-1\big)^{p} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c(n,v,p)\big(\zeta(n+v+2)-1\big)^{p}.$$